# How to invoke browser notification by a timed trigger in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to compare values of two cells and issue a browser notification.
So far I have been able to display browser message box.

I set the triggers to 5 minutes but following code does not execute. Manually it does.

```
function checkValue(e)

{

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();


var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Active Calls');//ss.gets


var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange('C5').getValue();
var valueShort = sheet.getRange('J5').getValue();
var scrip = sheet.getRange('A5').getValue();
//var scrip1 = "Short Pls"+script
//Browser.msgBox(scrip1+ " "+valueShort+ " ");
   // Browser.msgBox(scrip+ " "+valueShort+ " ");

//chrome.

if(valueToCheck < valueShort)

{
  Browser.msgBox(scrip+ ' short pls' +valueShort+ ' ');
 //var notify1 = new Notification =(scrip+ " "+valueShort+ " ");

//MailApp.sendEmail('amitbajaj768@gmail.com', 'Short call', 'at: ' + scrip+ '.');

}
```

Comment: Time-based triggers have no bound UI instance. So you won't get prompts, toasts, etc. Write a sidebar (which can run  regular JavaScript) to poll your sheet using `setInterval` and `google.script.run`, and then to display an `alert` or send an email (or just go back to sending an email and avoid the sidebar)